# What is the correct devenv.exe /Reset settings syntax?

Tags: azure-devops

How do I run the devenv.exe Reset Setting command in VSTS?

Should I just run it in a Command Window? If yes, what should the exact syntax be and which directory should I be in?

If not what should I do?

Comment: Removed unnecessary phrases, corrected grammar, introduced spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Just call it through Command Line task, for example:

1. Add Command Line task (Working folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`; Tool:`devenv.exe`; Arguments:`/resetuserdata`)

Comment: I figured it out through other search. VWDExpress file it was instead of devenv.exe in my directory. VS Express has this file only and not devenv.exe. I have now switched to Visual Studio 2017. Thanks for your reply starain-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

To all who run into this question: In VS Express 2012, its the VWDExpress executable file that you need to reset and NOT devenv.exe file. Other question threads suggest devenv.exe. Use VWDExpress file instead